# Perl resume a thread

Tags: multithreading, perl

I am trying to start a thread that I could suspend/ resume any time. Here is how I create the thread:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;
use threads::shared;
use Thread::Suspend;
use Thread::Semaphore;

sub createThread { 
    my $semaphore = Thread::Semaphore->new();
    my $thr = threads->create(sub {
        local $SIG{KILL} = sub { 
            die "Thread killed\n";
        };
        local $SIG{STOP} = sub { 
            print "sig stop\n";
            $semaphore->down();
        };
        local $SIG{CONT} = sub {
            $semaphore->up();
            print "sig cont\n";
        };

        my $test = sub {
            while (1) {
                $semaphore->down();
                print STDERR "Working process\n";
                sleep(2);
                $semaphore->up();
            }
        };

        return $test->();
    });

    return $thr->tid();
}
```

After retrieving the thread id (with `return $thr->tid();`). Then I try to pause it and the message `sig stop` is being printed and later when I try to resume it `sig cont` is not printed. Here is the code that suspends/ resumes the thread:

```
sub pause {
    my $class = shift;
    my $threadId = shift;
    my $thr = threads->object($threadId);

    if ($thr) {
        if ($thr->is_suspended() == 0) {
            $thr->kill('STOP');
            $thr->suspend();
            return "Process $threadId paused\n";
        } else {
            return "Process $threadId has to be resumed\n";
        }
    } else {
        return "Process $threadId not found\n";
    }
}

sub resume {
    my $class = shift;
    my $threadId = shift;
    my $thr = threads->object($threadId);

    if ($thr) {
        if ($thr->is_suspended() != 0) {
            $thr->resume();
            $thr->kill('CONT');
            return "Operation $threadId resumed\n";
        } else {
            return "Operation $threadId has not been paused\n";
        }
    } else {
        return "Process $threadId not found\n";
    }
}
```

After I resume a suspended thread, the message `Operation X was resumed` but `sig cont` isn't and the thread function is also not being resumed.

Comment: I really wouldn't mix signals with threads. They don't work as well as you think. Especially as your semaphore is global anyway, so you can use that to signal your process regardless.

Comment: Actually the semaphore object is inside the method that creates the thread (or you mean the semaphore is global according to the `test` method). Since mixing signals with threads is not a good idea, could you share another way to suspend/ resume a running thread.

Comment: And `$thr->suspend()` calls `$SIG{STOP}` (tested it with removing `$thr->kill('STOP');` line from `pause` method

Comment: Actually, see [threads](https://metacpan.org/pod/threads#THREAD-SIGNALLING): "*When safe signals is in effect (the default behavior - see "Unsafe signals" for more details), then signals may be sent and acted upon by individual threads.*" @bob_saginowski What is your `perl` version and are safe signals enabled?

Comment: @SinanÜnür my `perl` version is `v5.22.2` and nowhere in my code I enable safe signals

Comment: Well, they are enabled by default. They would be disabled if Perl has been built with PERL_OLD_SIGNALS (see perl -V) or the environment variable PERL_SIGNALS is set to unsafe (see "PERL_SIGNALS" in perlrun).

Comment: @SinanÜnür I added `$ENV{PERL_SIGNALS} = 'unsafe';` to my code but there is no difference;

Comment: Don't do that! There's a reason it's called unsafe.

Comment: @bob_saginowski You misunderstood what I was saying ... I am ***NOT*** recommending unsafe signals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's unclear whether you need [`Thread::Semaphore`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Thread::Semaphore) for a separate purpose, but it's not required for the functioning of [`Thread::Suspend`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Thread::Suspend)

I suspect the reason your suspend/resume isn't working is that you've overridden the signal handler that `Thread::Suspend` sets up for its own purposes

If I remove all the signal handlers and the `Thread::Semaphore` stuff, then your code works fine:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use threads;

use Thread::Suspend;

STDOUT->autoflush;


my $tid = create_thread();

for ( 1 .. 10 ) {
    sleep 5;
    print pause($tid);
    sleep 5;
    print resume($tid);
}


sub create_thread { 

    my $thr = threads->create( sub {
        while () {
            print "Working thread\n";
            sleep 1;
        }
    } );

    return $thr->tid;
}


sub pause {
    my ($tid) = @_;
    my $thr = threads->object($tid);

    return "Thread $tid not found\n" unless $thr;

    return "Thread $tid is already suspended\n" if $thr->is_suspended;

    $thr->suspend;
    return "Thread $tid paused\n";
}

sub resume {
    my ($tid) = @_;

    my $thr = threads->object($tid);

    return "Thread $tid not found\n" unless $thr;
    return "Thread $tid has not been paused\n" unless $thr->is_suspended;

    $thr->resume;
    return "Thread $tid resumed\n";
}
```

#### output

```
Working thread
Working thread
Working thread
Working thread
Working thread
Thread 1 paused
Thread 1 resumed
Working thread
Working thread
Working thread
Working thread
Working thread
Thread 1 paused
Thread 1 resumed
Working thread
Working thread
...
```

---

#### Update

There's no real need for your subroutines either. Here's a bare implementation

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use threads;

use Thread::Suspend;

STDOUT->autoflush;

sub thread_sub {

    while () {
        printf "Working thread %d\n", threads->self->tid;
        sleep 1;
    }
}

my $thr = threads->create(\&thread_sub);

for ( 1 .. 10 ) {

    sleep 5;

    if ( my $suspended = $thr->suspend ) {
        printf "Thread %d suspended\n", $suspended->tid;
    }

    sleep 5;

    if ( my $resumed = $thr->resume ) {
        printf "Thread %d resumed\n", $resumed->tid;
    }
}
```

#### output

```
Working thread 1
Working thread 1
Working thread 1
Working thread 1
Working thread 1
Working thread 1
Thread 1 suspended
Thread 1 resumed
Working thread 1
Working thread 1
Working thread 1
Working thread 1
Working thread 1
Working thread 1
Thread 1 suspended
Thread 1 resumed
Working thread 1
Working thread 1
Working thread 1
```

Comment: thank you for the great solution without semaphores, exactly what I am trying to achieve

Comment: @bob_saginowski: I'm also unsure whether you realise that your subroutines aren't necessary. I've updated my answer to add a simpler solution.

Answer (score 4):

No actual signals are being used here. Signals can only be sent to processes, not threads. From `$thread->kill`'s documentation:

> CAVEAT: The thread signalling capability provided by this module does not actually send signals via the OS. It emulates signals at the Perl-level such that signal handlers are called in the appropriate thread. For example, sending `$thr->kill('STOP')` does not actually suspend a thread (or the whole process), but does cause a `$SIG{'STOP'}` handler to be called in that thread (as illustrated above).

Since no actual signals are being used here, you're not mixing signals and threads. Good.

But it's an overly complicated design. Simply call `$sem->down_force()` in `pause` and `$sem->up()` in `resume`. There's no need for this to happen in the thread.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;
use Thread::Semaphore qw( );

{
    package Worker;

    sub new { 
        my $class = shift;
        return bless({ @_ }, $class);
    }

    sub thr    { return $_[0]{thr}        }
    sub tid    { return $_[0]{thr}->tid() }
    sub join   { $_[0]{thr}->join()       }
    sub pause  { $_[0]{sem}->down_force() }
    sub resume { $_[0]{sem}->up()         }
}

sub createThread {
    my $sem = Thread::Semaphore->new();
    my $thr = async {
        while (1) {
            $sem->down();
            ...
            $sem->up();
        }
    };

    return Worker->new( thr => $thr, sem => $sem );
}

sub pause  { my ($worker) = @_;  $worker->pause();  }
sub resume { my ($worker) = @_;  $worker->resume(); }
```

Of course, that assumes you only want to suspend the thread between work units. If you want to suspend the thread immediately, you don't need semaphores or "signals" at all<sup>[1]</sup>.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;
use Thread::Suspend;  # Must call import!

{
    package Worker;

    sub new { 
        my $class = shift;
        return bless({ @_ }, $class);
    }

    sub thr    { return $_[0]{thr}                           }
    sub tid    { return $_[0]{thr}->tid()                    }
    sub join   { $_[0]{thr}->join()                          }
    sub pause  { $_[0]{suspended}++ || $_[0]{thr}->suspend() }
    sub resume { --$_[0]{suspended} || $_[0]{thr}->resume()  }
}

sub createThread {
    my $thr = async {
        ...
    };

    return Worker->new( thr => $thr );
}

sub pause  { my ($worker) = @_;  $worker->pause();  }
sub resume { my ($worker) = @_;  $worker->resume(); }
```

Bonus: `$worker->pause; $worker->pause; $worker->resume; $worker->resume;` works fine for both of these methods (unlike the version in the question).

If you want to keep working using a tid instead of an object, just store the object in a hash keyed by tid.

---

1. At least, not in addition to Thread::Suspend, which uses a "signal" and what amounts to semaphores internally.

Comment: Tested. Need a couple of small fixes.

Comment: "down_force" sounds like a racer's handle or a bad super hero group name.